# page method not working for kaminari and mailboxer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari, mailboxer

I'm trying a couple things to find conversations where not all messages have been deleted and now the kaminari page method is not working. Could it be that conversations is a hash and the delete_if method changes the hash in an unexpected way? The page method works when used directly with `@mailbox.conversations.page(params[:page_1]).per(9)` so it must be the delete_if block that is making it not work.

Here's my action:

```
def index  
    @conversations = @mailbox.conversations.delete_if do |c|
        receipts = c.receipts_for @master
        (receipts.where(deleted: true).count == receipts.count)  
    end
    @conversations = @conversations.page(params[:page_1]).per(9)
end
```

I've also used .find_each instead of delete_if.

Here's the error I'm getting on my view

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `page' for #):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Params**

Firstly, are you sure you're meaning to be using `params[:page_1]` - if you're sending `?page=x`, it will just be `params[:page]`

---

**Method**

Secondly, your `undefined method` error is because you're not calling a valid ActiveRecord object:

```
def index  
    @conversations = @mailbox.conversations.delete_if do |c|
        receipts = c.receipts_for @master
        (receipts.where(deleted: true).count == receipts.count)  
    end
    @conversations = @conversations.page(params[:page_1]).per(9)
end
```

What's `@conversations`?

[Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) & [Will_Paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) both override the SQL query you'll make from your Controller / Model. This means you have to call their `page` & `per` methods on ActiveRecord calls:

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#simple-scope-based-api):

> Everything is method chainable with less “Hasheritis”. You know,
>   that's the Rails 3 way. No special collection class or anything for
>   the paginated values, instead using a general AR::Relation instance.
>   So, of course you can chain any other conditions before or after the
>   paginator scope

I believe you'd be better doing something like this:

```
def index  
    @mailbox.conversations.each do |c|
        receipts = c.receipts_for @master
        c.destroy if (receipts.where(deleted: true).count == receipts.count)  
    end
    @conversations = @mailbox.conversations.page(params[:page]).per(9)
end
```

---

**Update**

If you don't want to `destroy` your items, you could use an [ActiveRecord association extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) like this:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def index  
    @conversations = @mailbox.conversations.receipts.page(params[:page]).per(9)
end

#app/models/model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :conversations do

        def receipts
            receipts = joins(:receipts_for).select("COUNT(*)")
            proxy_association.target.delete_if do
                receipts.where(deleted: true) == receipts
            end
        end

    end
end
```

This will need tweaking, but hopefully will give you some ideas as to what you can do

Comment: Thank you for your reply yes it was setting the conversations variable at first that messed it up.

Comment: Careful, I don't think Mlennie actually wants to `destroy` any objects.  Mlennie is just trying to get a set/array/ActiveRecord::Relation 'where not all messages have been deleted', and `delete_if` accomplishes this (if inefficiently).  Using `delete_if` returns an array where all objects that meet the criteria specified in the block have been removed.  But it doesn't actually `destroy` any persisted data from the database.

Comment: Agreed. If she wanted to do what you said, she should use a `scope` or `where` call to load the specific data

Comment: @johnnycakes yes it's true I don't want to actually destroy any objects so I stayed with delete_if. Rich Peck could you please specify how I could use a scope or where for this?

Comment: Updated - need to tweak it, but it's what I'd look into

Comment: It's similar code just extracted into the model. AR association extensions literally just allow you to create a method you can call on the extension (in your case `conversations`). It's just taking the code from your controller & applying to the model